# Results show 0 even though user put different numbers?

Tags: vba

So, I'm making an array in VBA, and I have to make a two-dimensional array.

Everything seems to be working fine, but the results show 0 even though I want them to show the result that the user has put.

Here's the code:

```
Public Sub Masiivs()

    Dim Arr(5, 5) As Integer
    Dim Arg As String
    Dim X, Y As Integer
    Dim Rezult As String
    Dim I, J As Long
    Y = 1

        While Y < 26
            X = InputBox("Ievadiet masīva skaitļus Nr. " + CStr(Y), "Datu Ievade")
            Y = Y + 1
        Wend

    For I = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        Arg = Arg + " " + CStr(Arr(I, I))

   Next I

   MsgBox Arg

End Sub
```

Apologies, some of the words are in Latvian, but it's not that important. It simply asks to input each array's number.

Comment: There's at least 2 problems. 1) you don't assign `X` into a slot in `Arr`. 2) if you did (1) you still don't iterate `Arr` over both dimensions.

Comment: Well, first you never write anything in your array... and second you only output the sum of the diagonal terms of the array.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie So should I change my Arr(I, I) to Arr(X, X) or something? Thanks.

Comment: You should at least be using a statement like `Arr(i, j) = ...` at some point. Anyway - see the answer from @gizlmo - it is pretty useful and a good way to code what you want to do

Comment: @RobinMackenzie Yes, his answer did help, but now there's a new question I asked him. Hoping for an answer. I'm still new to this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You are never storing the values inside of your array, so they will never be saved. Try something like this:

```
Dim X As Integer, Y As Integer
Dim Arr(5, 5) As Integer
Dim Arg As String

'Loop through the first dimenion of Arr
For X = LBound(Arr, 1) To UBound(Arr, 1) Step 1

    'Loop thourgh the second dimension of Arr
    For Y = LBound(Arr, 2) To UBound(Arr, 2) Step 1

        'Ask for Input and save it at current position
        Arr(X, Y) = InputBox("Ievadiet masiva skaitlus Nr. " + CStr(Y), "Datu Ievade")
        'add value to Arg
        Arg = Arg & Arr(X, Y)
    Next Y
Next X

MsgBox Arg
```

---

Edit:
To add spaces to your Messagebox, change the line: `Arg = Arg & Arr(X, Y)` to `Arg = Arg & " " & Arr(X, Y)`.  The output will look something like this: `1 2 3 4`. To cut off the leading space, use `Trim()`: `Arg = Trim(Arg)`

To Enter a space after every fifth element, add `Arg = Chr(10) & Arg` between `Next Y` and `Next X`. So everytime the inner loop ends, you add a linebreak to the string.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to give me the results of user's input, but how can I make a space between each input, and put them in a new line after every 5th array input?

Comment: @Arthur  move `Arg = Arg & " " & Arr(X, Y)` after the line of `Next Y`

Comment: @ShaiRado That seemed to work. Now the only thing left is a new line after every 5th input. How can I do that? Apologies for so many simple questions.

Comment: @ShaiRado added an example to the answer.

Comment: @gizlmo Thanks! EDIT: Actually, for some reason the space didn't work. It ended up making 5 spaces, and then showing all of the results in one line.

Comment: @gizlmo It seems like I managed to do it myself! What I did was: I put Arg = Arg + vbNewLine between Next Y and Next X.